# Estoy encallado con un ej de clase el cual tengo que utilizar funciones (se debe hacer sin arrays)

Tags: java

El enunciado es el siguiente:

> Realiza una función que calcule una serie de números aleatorios enteros. Los parámetros de la función serán: el valor mínimo, el valor máximo, y la cantidad de números a mostrar.

Yo estoy haciendo esto pero no se como continuarlo y me gustaría saber si hay mas formas, cualquier información de ayuda es bienvenida un saludo. pd : losiento por el posible desastre que es jajaja.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maximo = 0, minimo = 0, quantNums = 0, numAleatorio = 0;
        System.out.println("Introdueix la quantitat de nombres aleatoris: ");
        quantNums = sc.nextInt();
        for (int numsAleatorios, i = 1; i <= quantNums; i++) {
            numsAleatorios = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
            numAleatorio = numsAleatorios;
            System.out.println("" + numAleatorio);
        }
        Nombres(maximo, minimo, quantNums, numAleatorio);

    }

    static void Nombres(int maxim, int minimo, int quantNums, int numAleatorio) {
        quantNums = quantNums;
        maximo = 

        System.out.println("La cantidad de nombres introducida es de: " + quantNums);
        System.out.println("El número màxim és: " + maximo);
        System.out.println("El número mínim és: " + minimo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si no hara uso de un array, podes validar los valores requeridos en el mismo ciclo for donde obtienes los numeros aleatorios

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//el minimo tomara el mayor valor posible aleatorio para que no se afecte en el ciclo
           int maximo = 0, minimo = 100, quantNums = 0, numAleatorio = 0;
           System.out.println("Introdueix la quantitat de nombres aleatoris: ");
           quantNums = sc.nextInt();
    
           for (int i=0; i<quantNums; i++) {
               numAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
               System.out.println("" + numAleatorio);
    
    
            if(numAleatorio > maximo){//si el nro aleatorio es mayor al maximo
            maximo = numAleatorio;//el maximo tomara ese valor
    
            }
    
            if(numAleatorio < minimo){// si es menor 
            minimo = numAleatorio;// tomara ese valor
            }  
     
           }
          
           System.out.println("La cantidad de nombres introducida es de: " + quantNums);
           System.out.println("El número màxim és: " + maximo);
           System.out.println("El número mínim és: " + minimo);
       }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Ahora entiendo , mi error a sido entender mal el enunciado desde el principio. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @MiguelM si te sirvio la respuesta , no olvides marcarla como aceptada, dandole en el icono de ✔,saludos